# i am runnig a chef client and i getta issues or error

Tags: linux

I am trying chef and it is giving this error

> dnf_package[httpd] action install
> Error executing action `install` on resource 'dnf_package[httpd]'

Code for error:

```
   package "httpd" do
       action :install
       end
```

I am new to linux and chef i dont how to slove this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
dnf_package 'httpd' do
   action :install
end
```